# Excel COUNTIFS: Formula doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba, filter, countif

I have a question regarding the formula "=COUNTIFS". I have a table with several columns, one is "Project name" and the others are "category 1" and "category2".

The single "=COUNTIF" works fine for me, see below (I am filtering for the word "Preferential" in two columns on the sheet "Entries":

`=COUNTIF(Entries!E2:F1099, "Preferential")`

The double one "=COUNTIFS" does not work though. Can you please tell me what I do wrong? This is what I am using:

`=COUNTIFS(Entries!E2:F1099, "Preferential", Entries!A2:A1099, "Selling GPI")`

I always just get the error "#VALUE!".

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation found [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842):

> Important: Each additional range must have the same number of rows and columns as the criteria_range1 argument. The ranges do not have to be adjacent to each other.

In your case, the criteria 1 range has 2 columns, while the criteria 2 range has only one.

You can change the formula by :

```
=COUNTIFS(Entries!E2:E1099, "Preferential", Entries!F2:F1099, "Preferential", Entries!A2:A1099, "Selling GPI")
```

It should solve your problem. [1]

[1] or maybe not, the second formula implies that "Preferential" should be in both columns E and F

---

**Edit**: Corrected formula: If the objective is to count the rows where either E or F are "Preferential" and A is "Selling GPI":

```
=COUNTIFS(Entries!E2:E1099,"Preferential",Entries!A2:A1099,"Selling GPI")+COUNTIFS(Entries!F2:F1099,"Preferential",Entries!A2:A1099,"Selling GPI")-COUNTIFS(Entries!E2:E1099,"Preferential",Entries!F2:F1099,"Preferential",Entries!A2:A1099,"Selling GPI")
```

The first COUNTIFS will count rows for columns E and A, the second for F and A, an the third will remove the rows counted twice.

If the objective is to count occurrences of "Preferential" in columns E or F and of "Selling GPI" in column A, you can use:

```
=COUNTIF(Entries!E2:F1099,"Selling GPI")+COUNTIF(Entries!A2:A1099,"Selling GPI")
```

Comment: Hi Vincent,

Thank you for the help! Indeed, I did not know that about this forumula, thank you very much! But as you said, it does not work now: "Preferential" can either appear in the column E or F. Do you have any other idea? :)

Edit: I found a neat workaround: Since column "B" will never only say "Selling GPI", I will just do this. THanks! :)

Comment: Well, you can use the formula thrice to count for both column E and column F (see edited answer)